# Unions of fixed size structures for use in safe context

Tags: c#

I'm working with packets that I can receive or send as a Byte array,
that has a fixed structure. So I'm trying to create an effective
union as follows:

```
using System; // etc..

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public const int PktMaxSize = 124;
        // ...etc..
        // ...will use Pkt structure below...
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Pkt
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
        fixed Byte bytes[Main.PktMaxSize]; // complete byte pkt

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
        fixed Byte PktID[8];

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(8)]
        UInt16 Properties;

        // ...etc..
    }
}
```

I get a C# error

> Pointers and size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context

What do I need to do to be able to create and use "unsafe" structures in a safe env?

Thanks for your help - open to any suggestions as to how to handle packet structures that can easily be converted to and from a fixed byte stream being received by (or sent by) a C++ interop class.

Answer (score 3):

The use of the `fixed` keyword requires `Pkt` and all methods using it to be declared unsafe, e.g.,

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public unsafe struct Pkt
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    fixed Byte bytes[124];

    ...
}
```

If you don't want to use unsafe code you can declare `Pkt` as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Pkt
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 124)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    Byte[] bytes;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    Byte[] PktID;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    UInt16 Properties;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the unsafe keyword on the method or block:

```
unsafe static void DoSomethingUnsafe()
{
  // use Pkt structure
}

static void DoSomething()
{
  // do safe things
  unsafe
  {
    // use Pkt structure
  }
}
```

You must also enable unsafe code via the /unsafe option or the Project > Properties > Build tab in Visual Studio.